# Candy Crush as an integer programming problem

Tags: puzzle, combinatorial-game-theory, integer-programming, algorithmic-game-theory

I'm trying to model the basic version of a match-three game, where the player (has a maximum number of swaps) must swap any two adjacent gems (no diagonals) in an 8x8 grid of gems in order to match three of the same color in a row. The gems can be matched horizontally or vertically. Gameplay continues until the user gets the required score or arrive to the limit of moves.

I have a matrix of 8 by 8, each cell contain a certain color (i have 6 in my model).
I don't know where to start, I didn't find relevant research papers about that.

- How can i model gem swapping ?
- How can i model the scoring and deletion of the 3-matched gems ?

Comment: why do you think it reduces to an integer programming problem ? and the [peg solitaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peg_solitaire) can be solved with integer programming, you should look how.

Comment: i know how to resolve the problem using Branch And Bound for example, but i'm interested in modeling the problem in Mixed Integer Programming or a CSP.

Comment: a state of the peg solitaire is : $0$ or $1$ for indicating if there is a piece at the $k$th place, hence a $K$ boolean vector, and each move is multiplying it by a $K \times K$ matrix : one matrix for each possible move. hence a state of the peg solitaire is $\prod_{n=1}^N A_n u_0$ where $u_0$ is the initial state and the $A_n$ are the moves played at the $n$th round. finally, the constraints let defining when and how a move is allowed or not. your game works in the same way.